# I want to download "Download Windows 10 Technical Preview ISO" .ios file in my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows, internet, downloads, download-manager

I want to download "Download Windows 10 Technical Preview ISO" .ios file in my ubuntu 14.04.So that I can use it in pendrive. Can anyone give me the glimpse to how to do it using terminal ?
I want to store it in seperate folder on my desktop!

Answer (score 0):

Mosttimes this works: Find the URL. Then put the URL in command line after a `wget`. [But knowing MicroSoft you need to sign up 1st](http://www.askvg.com/download-windows-10-free-technical-preview/) so a command line method is not possible.

And then use something like brasero to burn it to a dvd or use the USB disk creator to install it into an USB.